# Why so many permutations of parameters in this TypeScript code

Tags: typescript, rxjs5

I was looking through the source code of [RxJS 5 combineLatest](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/src/operator/combineLatest.ts) and found lots of permutations of a call with numbered parameters.

Why is this done when there are rest parameters?

Are there any upcoming features of TypeScript that will make this less verbose?

I was wondering if it was to do with typing of rest parameters or perhaps intellisense?

```
export interface CombineLatestSignature<T> {
  <R>(project: (v1: T) => R): Observable<R>;
  <T2, R>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, project: (v1: T, v2: T2) => R): Observable<R>;
  <T2, T3, R>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, project: (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3) => R): Observable<R>;
  <T2, T3, T4, R>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>, project: (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3, v4: T4) => R): Observable<R>;
  <T2, T3, T4, T5, R>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>, v5: ObservableInput<T5>, project: (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3, v4: T4, v5: T5) => R): Observable<R>;
  <T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, R>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>, v5: ObservableInput<T5>, v6: ObservableInput<T6>, project: (v1: T, v2: T2, v3: T3, v4: T4, v5: T5, v6: T6) => R): Observable<R>;

  <T2>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>): Observable<[T, T2]>;
  <T2, T3>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>): Observable<[T, T2, T3]>;
  <T2, T3, T4>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4]>;
  <T2, T3, T4, T5>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>, v5: ObservableInput<T5>): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
  <T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>, v5: ObservableInput<T5>, v6: ObservableInput<T6>): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;

  <R>(...observables: Array<ObservableInput<any> | ((...values: Array<any>) => R)>): Observable<R>;
  <R>(array: ObservableInput<any>[]): Observable<R>;
  <R>(array: ObservableInput<any>[], project: (...values: Array<any>) => R): Observable<R>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest parameters all have to declared with the same type so it's impossible to accurately model this particular interface with just rest parameters. I don't see any way this interface could be made less verbose without losing useful type information.

Comment: The pattern seems to be outlined on this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1024), but there is a proposal for variadics that sounds like a possible future replacement linked to the issue.